# Пропало автодополнение кода

Tags: android, android-studio

Пропало всплывающее меню с автодополнением кода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При наборе студия не предлагает ничего:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно его вернуть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалите папку .idea в корне проекта. Потом переоткройте проект.

У Вас форсмажорчик, такого в принципе быть не должно. У меня за всю историю использование IDE от джет брейнс такое случилось только раз (пропадание автодополнения). Не думаю что у вас по нескольку раз на дню будет повторятся сей инцидент. Чтобы предотвратить повторение кокретно Вашего случая нужно сначала докопаться до причины, это можете сделать только Вы. Посему можно просто помнить про `.idea` :)

Comment: При повторном возникновении проблемы какие способы борьбы еще существуют. Не удалять же ее постоянно.

Answer (score 1):

Снимите галочку с **`File -> Power Save Mode`**

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Если посмотреть внимательно на картинку автора топика, то в правом нижнем углу видно включение "Power Save Mode".